# How to get latest two rows with certain value by date in SQL

Tags: oracle, select, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

My question is that I have certain table with some `varchar2` values and insert date.
What I want to do is to get latest two such entries grouped by this varchar2 value
Is it possible to include some `top(2)` instead of `max` in Oracle `group by` ?

Comment: Or maybe there's at least possibility to run it one by one query for last entry and second last?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle+greatest-n-per-group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** Updated to not count duplicate date value for the same `varchar2`.

Replaced `RANK()` with `DENSE_RANK()` such that it assigns consecutive ranks, then used `distinct` to eliminate the duplicates.

You can use [DENSE_RANK()](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rank-dense-rank-first-last-analytic-functions.php)

```
SELECT DISTINCT TXT, ENTRY_DATE
  FROM (SELECT txt,
               entry_date,
               DENSE_RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY txt ORDER BY entry_date DESC)
                  AS myRank
          FROM tmp_txt) Q1
 WHERE Q1.MYRANK < 3
ORDER BY txt, entry_date DESC
```

Input:

```
txt | entry_date

xyz | 03/11/2014
xyz | 25/11/2014
abc | 19/11/2014
abc | 04/11/2014
xyz | 20/11/2014
abc | 02/11/2014
abc | 28/11/2014
xyz | 25/11/2014
abc | 28/11/2014
```

Result:

```
txt | entry_date

abc | 28/11/2014
abc | 19/11/2014
xyz | 25/11/2014
xyz | 20/11/2014
```

Comment: and how to omit the case in which I might have two entries with the same date? then it displays both with rank 2 instead of either one entry or two with rank 1